# hover effect respective to the value of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

I have 5 images. When I **hover** on the 5th image the first 5 images background-color must be changed. When I hover on the 4th image the first 4 images background color must be changed, similarly for 3rd image first 3, 2nd image first 2, 1st image the 1st one background-color must be changed. How to write the CSS?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#images img").click(function(){
    var va = $(this).attr("name");
    if(va=='5'){
        $('.two,.three,.four,.one,.five').addClass('active');
    }else if(va=='4'){
        $('.two,.three,.four,.one').addClass('active');
        $('.five').removeClass('active');
    }else if(va=='3'){
        $('.two,.three,.one').addClass('active');
        $('.four,.five').removeClass('active');
    }else if(va=='2'){
        $('.two,.one').addClass('active');
        $('.three,.four,.five').removeClass('active');
    }else if(va=='1'){
        $('.one').addClass('active');
        $('.two,.three,.four,.five').removeClass('active');
    }
    $("#result_value").text(va);
});
$("#images img").mouseover(function(){
    var va = $(this).attr("name");
    if(va=='5'){
        $('.two,.three,.four,.one,.five').addClass('active');
    }else if(va=='4'){
        $('.two,.three,.four,.one').addClass('active');
        $('.five').removeClass('active');
    }else if(va=='3'){
        $('.two,.three,.one').addClass('active');
        $('.four,.five').removeClass('active');
    }else if(va=='2'){
        $('.two,.one').addClass('active');
        $('.three,.four,.five').removeClass('active');
    }else if(va=='1'){
        $('.one').addClass('active');
        $('.two,.three,.four,.five').removeClass('active');
    }
    });
    $("#images img").mouseleave(function(){
        $('.one,.two,.three,.four,.five').removeClass('active');
     });
   });
   <style>
     .clr:hover{
      background-color:#FFD700;
     }

     .active{
  background-color:#FFD700;
     }
   </style>
   </head>

   <body>
    <div class="images" id="images">
     <form name="imagediv" id="imagediv" method="post">
      <img src="star1.png" class="one" alt="Number 1" name="1" width="42" height="42">
      <img src="star2.png" class="two" alt="Number 1" name="2" width="42" height="42">
      <img src="star3.png" class="three" alt="Number 1" name="3" width="42" height="42">
      <img src="star4.png" class="four" alt="Number 1" name="4" width="42" height="42">
      <img src="star5.png" class="five" alt="Number 1" name="5" width="42" height="42">

     </form>
    </div>
     <div class="result_value" id="result_value" ></div>
    </body>
```

For click and mousehover I have written the save logic so for click the added class must not be removed, for mousehover the class must be removed after mouseout butthe class is not getting removed, for this I used mouseout but this mouseout for the image class and this mouseout is applying for click also, whereas for click the added class must not be removed on mouseout and the background color is removed for mousehover a

Comment: I'm not sure about how to do exactly what you're trying to do in CSS, but I can easily think of how to do this with JS.

Comment: You can do it with css...that's why I am asking...how does your html look. Is it ul..li...or div ?

Comment: I have edited and written what I have done and clearly explained what I require

Comment: Here's the fiddle for anyone else trying to understand this: http://jsfiddle.net/cHD7k/

Comment: And here is one where the "clicked" value is saved: http://jsfiddle.net/R67r7/1/ It's not doable with CSS only (the state saving part). *What is the question tough?*

Comment: You need to unbind the mouseout event on click event to make it work properly. Check http://jsfiddle.net/cHD7k/2/

Comment: latest one with working code : http://jsfiddle.net/cHD7k/3/

Comment: State is lost on mouseover/out in your latest attempt.

Comment: OH ya, the code was not updated @SergiuParaschiv Check http://jsfiddle.net/cHD7k/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<img src="star1.png" class="one s1" alt="Number 1" name="1" width="42" height="42">
<img src="star2.png" class="two s2" alt="Number 1" name="2" width="42" height="42">
<img src="star3.png" class="three s3" alt="Number 1" name="3" width="42" height="42">
<img src="star4.png" class="four s4" alt="Number 1" name="4" width="42" height="42">
<img src="star5.png" class="five s5" alt="Number 1" name="5" width="42" height="42">


$("#images img").click(function(){
    var va = $(this).attr("name");
    $(this).prevAll().addClass("active");
    $("#result_value").text(va);
});

$("#images img").mouseover(function(){
    var va = $(this).attr("name");
    $(this).addClass("active").prevAll("img").addClass('active');
    $(this).nextAll("img").removeClass('active');
});

$("#images img").mouseleave(function(){
    var va = 1 * $("#result_value").text();

    if(va > 0) {
        $('.s' + va).addClass('active').prevAll("img").addClass('active');        
        $('.s' + va).nextAll().removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $("#images img").removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Try and switch all your code to "s1, s2, ..." instead of "one, two...". It's far easier to build those class names programatically and, as you can see, you need to.
Also try not to use `name` any more on anything other than form inputs. It's non-standard HTML. Maybe switch to HTML5 and the `data-` attributes class.

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/nR6c6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `nextAll()` & `prevAll()` to make it look simple. You need to unbind the mouseout event on click event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var index;
    $("#images img").click(function () {
        var va = $(this).attr("name");
        $(this).addClass("active").prevAll().addClass("active");
        $(this).nextAll("img").removeClass('active');
        index = $("#images img").index(this);
        $("#result_value").text(va);       
    });
    $("#images img").mouseover(function () {
        var va = $(this).attr("name");
 $(this).addClass("active").prevAll("img").addClass('active');
        $(this).nextAll("img").removeClass('active');

    });
    $("#images img").mouseout(function () {
        $("#images img").removeClass('active');
        if(index) {
              $("#images img").eq(index).addClass("active").prevAll("img").addClass("active");
             $("#images img").eq(index+1).removeClass("active");

        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cHD7k/7/)**

Comment: I still don't get this question. The original code, though bad, works.

Comment: What i understood from the question is, the OP has events for mouseenter, mouseleave and click. But when the OP clicks, even the mouseleave event is fired. Like for example: On click, the OP wants to make the active class to be there. But since in mouseLeave event removes the active class, the OP wants to prevent it. that's what i did via unbind & bind :)

Comment: **@mohamedrians** - using your code I can bring my code to less number of line. But my problem is not sloved. The same problem which I mentioned in my query is with the code you wrote. Could you solve the problem in your code. The answer of **Sergiu Paraschiv** which can be seen in the comments is perfectly fine, but can you show it in the above code.

Comment: **@mohamedrians** where have you written the bind and unbind? I can't find it in your code

Comment: You will find .off & a settimeout inside the click event

Comment: **@mohamedrians** In the jsfiddle link you mentioned, once click on any of the image and mouse out and again mouseover and again mouseout. The clicked event is getting removed in this sequence. The clickeed even must remain the same for any number of mouseover and mouseout functions, it must changed only for the other click event.

Comment: It's still not working. Try clicking and then mouse over/out some other image. State is lost.

Comment: I feel that's the requirement.. When you click and leave without hovering over image the state must be preserved and if you hover over some other image then state can be lost like the beginning

Comment: **mohamedrias** no the state of the click event must remain even for mouseover/mouseout and it must change only for other click event.

Comment: now the mouseover is not working after click event :(

Comment: Ahh, i'm finding it difficult to understand the requirement :D